# SSRS Use page footer as group footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In SSRS, I have a rectangle with textboxes to show some summarized data and I placed this rectangle inside the page footer.  Is there anyway in SSRS where I can show this page footer only on the last page of each group?

Right now, if my first group has 2 pages, the footer will show on both pages, but I'd only want it on the last page per group.  Is there a trick/workaround I can use to make this happen?

Comment: Other than adding a table that looks like your footer to the end of your group I don't "think" you can do this with a 'real' footer. SSRS Header/Footer control is a bit limited. I did think of having each group as a subreport but even then there is no way to show a footer ONLY on the page page. Maybe somebody else knows better though

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column in your group to calculate the footer visibility expression.

```
= Iif(CountRows("groupname") = RunningValue(1, Count, "groupname"), False, True)
```

Now on your footer rectangle set the visibility expression equal to the value of the textbox containing the calculation
eg. `= ReportItems!Textbox18.value`

Group with one page
[image]

1st page of group with more pages
[image]

Last page of group
[image]